# Cluster already exists aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I try to create a cluster, I get a message that `Stack [eksctl-eksdemo2-cluster] already exists` but when I try to delete it I get a message `is not authorized to perform: eks:DescribeCluster on resource: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:327352963247:cluster/eksdemo1` and I can't seem to manually delete it as I do not find it in the aws console. When I try to create one with a new name I see the error `user is not authorized to perform: eks:TagResource on resource: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:327352963247:cluster/eksdemo3`. What roles do I need to create a cluster as it seems that at each stage I need to attach a new policy

Comment: You will need to attach the AmazonEKSClusterPolicy and AmazonEKSServicePolicy to your IAM user in order to create an EKS cluster and all associated resources. You can find these policies from the IAM console. Additionally, you will also need to attach any other required policies for any additional resources being created.

Comment: All of the diagnostic messages that you report seem to be (annoyingly!) accurate. Go have a chat with your local AWS account admin, possibly the person who can use the root login. You have business goals to accomplish, and your current access level won't let you do that. Your admin can help.